# jQuery Script is not executing after a button click in update panel

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

I have a button inside a update panel, & I am using jQuery scripting to style the elements in the page. Initially the page loads & css style applies on it along with the script which have some jQuery code. i.e. Initially everything is OK. But when I click on the button it causes a server post-back(necessary), the CSS style is applied but Script is not loaded. Please help me out with this.

Comment: can we have some code or example???

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your script (if using .Net 3.5 or less). It will notify the Microsoft Ajax Library that the JavaScript file has been loaded.

```
if (typeof (Sys) != 'undefined')
{
    Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded();
}
```

Note: This is obsolete in .Net 4

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your code (best as a named function) as part of the [`endRequest` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx) as well, for example you can have a named function like this:

```
function doStuff() {
  //do whatever here
}
```

Then run that function where needed:

```
//run on DOM ready
$(doStuff);
//also run it when UpadtePanels finish/reload
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(doStuff);
```